# Filtering data in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a big database with sales for the branches of the supermarket network in Excel. I want to make a functionality that each branch sees only sales that belong to this branch. Each branch has a unique ID.

What come to my mind is to assign to each branch a specific password in an additional sheet. Then, make the original data and the passwords hidden.

Once a branch opens a file there is a sheet requesting id and password. Then there is a button that runs a macros for filtering the data.

I know that this solution is pretty trivial. That's why, I was wondering, if there is any better (more protected) way to solve this? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Consider using a real database instead of Excel. Excel is no database tool, its main use is to calculate tables. With eg. a SQL database you could easily use different queries for different privileges. It is almost impossible to get this secure with Excel. Most techniques would only obscure your data, hidden data is no secure data.

Comment: What kind of database have you got. Have you considered putting security functionality in the database?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, the issue is that we wanted really quick solution. I realize that having a db, would do things much better

Comment: @LJ01, as it is written, the data is in Excel.

Comment: @tolik quick means dirty in this case. If you are up for security, I say no chance with Excel.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, what about the Access? Is it considered as a secure enough DB? After double check, I go info that the data is stored in Access originally

Comment: WIthout a real database I'd suggest running code that filtered the data to each store and then saving that filtered data to it's own workbook before sending to the store (I'm assuming the finished workbook is emailed out).  The best security in Excel is not to include the data you don't want them to see.

Comment: @tolik I confirm Darren's suggestion. And I wouldn't consider Access a "real" database. And you would have the same issue to "hide" that data. A real database would run on a server, that hands out only that part of data to the user, that the user has the privilege for. So here comes the security part: The user will never have access to data he doesn't have the privilege. But what you considered in Excel/Access is that the user has **all** data on his computer but you try to hide some (which is not secure). Never hand out data that the user doesn't have the privilege for is the best securitiy.